# Error while using jpexport ( exporting jprofiler .jps files )

Tags: java, performance, profiling, jprofiler, apm

I have a JProfiler snapshot file(.jps) which is created using offline profiling.

While I'm trying to export it using JPexport script getting below error:

> /opt/jprofiler9/bin$ jpexport ~/test.jps HotSpots ~/HotSpots.html
>   Loading /home/pavan/test.jps
>   **JProfiler has not been initialized. Please run the JProfiler executable first**

Could any one please elaborate what it mean and what it need to be done to successfully export views in html.

NOTE : I've started my application in tomcat and add `agentpath` to `catalina_opts` in set environment

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-agentpath:/opt/jprofiler9/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=offline,id=80,nowait,config=/opt/jprofiler9/api/samples/common/config.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

jpexport requires that the JProfiler license has been entered. When you start the JProfiler GUI, you are prompted to enter the license key, then jpexport will work.

On a headless machine, copy `$HOME/.jprofiler9/config.xml` from a machine with a GUI where a license key was entered to the same path.